# Como serializar um color com Json?

Tags: c#, json

Tenho o seguinte código, em que estou a tentar serializar e deserializar uma classe que possui 2 variáveis `Color`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Color cor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
    Color cor2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
    JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string serializado = serial.Serialize(new cores() { corI=cor, corE=cor2 });
    cores teste = serial.Deserialize<cores>(serializado);
    Console.WriteLine(teste.corI + " - " + teste.corE);
}

class cores
{
    public Color corI { get; set; }
    public Color corE { get; set; }
}
```

Porem, a saída deste programa é:

```
Color [Empty] - Color [Empty]
```

Ou seja, não funcionou.

Minha duvida é, porque Json não funciona para o Color? Como fazer funcionar?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil apenas guardar a cor no formato Hex ou RGB em sua estrutura Json?

Comment: Além disso, eu não sei se é possível obter os mesmos resultados serializando uma estrutura, já que o Color é uma estrutura e não uma classe. De qualquer forma, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27584530/5429980) para ver se lhe serve de ajuda.

Comment: @gato Eu já arrumei isso, estou passando um array de inteiros. Mas fiz a pergunta porque isso me deixou meio encabulado e eu queria saber o porque não funcionava.

Comment: Você tem algum motivo pra utilizar o `JavaScriptSerializer` para serializar para json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a classe `JavaScriptSerializer` a cor é serializada, porém, na hora de deserializar ele não consegue criar os objetos novamente, agora utilizando uma biblioteca própria para trabalhar com Json, a estrutura Cor é construida novamente. Fiz as comparações abaixo:

---

### JavaScriptSerializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer serial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string serializado = serial.Serialize(new cores() { corI=cor, corE=cor2 });
Console.Write(serializado);
```

**Saida:**

> `{
>      "corI":{
>         "R":255,
>         "G":0,
>         "B":0,
>         "A":255,
>         "IsKnownColor":false,
>         "IsEmpty":false,
>         "IsNamedColor":false,
>         "IsSystemColor":false,
>         "Name":"ffff0000"
>      },
>      "corE":{
>         "R":0,
>         "G":0,
>         "B":255,
>         "A":255,
>         "IsKnownColor":false,
>         "IsEmpty":false,
>         "IsNamedColor":false,
>         "IsSystemColor":false,
>         "Name":"ff0000ff"
>      }
>   }`

**Deserealizando**

```
cores teste = serial.Deserialize<cores>(serializado);
Console.WriteLine(teste.corI + " - " + teste.corE);
```

**Saida:**

O `JavaScriptSerializer` não conseguiu construir o objeto novamente

> Color [Empty] - Color [Empty]

---

### NewtonSoft.Json

Agora utilizando uma classe que trabalha com Json, no caso eu utilizei a biblioteca NewtonSoft.Json, o resultado é diferente:

```
string serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new cores() { corI = cor, corE = cor2 });
Console.Write(serializado);
```

**Saida**

Saida é bem mais simples

> {"corI":"255, 0, 0","corE":"0, 0, 255"}

**Deserealizando**

```
cores teste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cores>(serializado);
Console.WriteLine(teste.corI + " - " + teste.corE);
```

**Saida**

Ele consegue reconstruir o objeto.

> Color [Red] - Color [Blue]

---

**Conclusão**

Não sei o motivo pelo qual você está utilizando esta classe, mas me parece não ser uma boa opção, quando você quer apenas transformar um objeto em string, recomendo você a utilizar uma das bibliotecas de Json, que são otimizadas e próprias para isso.